# Python/SQLALCHEMY: Unsure on how to user 'filter_by'

Tags: python, html, sqlalchemy

I am trying to display only the posts on a website that was made by the current logged in user. I believe I need the filter_by keyword. I looked through the documentation for SQlalchemy but am still having difficulty with the syntax and getting this to work:

Imports:

`from project.models import User, Post`

`from flask_login import login_user, current_user, logout_user, login_required`

Routes:

`@app.route("/history")`

`def history():`

```
page = request.args.get('page', 1, type=int)
posts = Post.query.order_by(Post.end_date.desc()).filter_by(User.id==current_user)
return render_template('history.html', posts=posts, title='About')`
```

Users/Post page:

`class User(db.Model, UserMixin):`

```
id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
username = db.Column(db.String(20), unique=True, nullable=False)
email = db.Column(db.String(120), unique=True, nullable=False)
password = db.Column(db.String(60), nullable=False)
posts = db.relationship('Post', backref='author', lazy=True)`
```

`class Post(db.Model):`

```
id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
identification = db.Column(db.String(10), nullable=False)
date_posted = db.Column(db.Date, nullable=False, default=datetime.utcnow)
notes = db.Column(db.Text)
user_id = db.Column(db.Integer, db.ForeignKey('user.id'), nullable=False)`
```

Errors:
When I type filter_by(User.id==current_user):

`TypeError: filter_by() takes 1 positional argument but 2 were given`

When I type filter_by(user.id==current_user)not sure if user is suppose to be capitalized:

`NameError: name 'user' is not defined`

When I type
filter_by(user_id=current_user)

`sqlalchemy.exc.ArgumentError: Object User('test', 'test@yahoo.com'), '1' is not legal as a SQL literal value`

Thanks for your help

Comment: I tried: filter(Post.user_id==current_user.id), but my page brings up no posts at all which makes me believe I messed something up in there. If I do 'current_user' rather than 'current_user.id' I get back the last error code in the my original question. Any more help would be appreciated!

Answer (score 1):

I had similar issues too, try this.

Instead of:
filter_by(User.id==current_user)

Try:
filter_by(id=current_user)

Answer (score -1):

It may help us if you copy the error.

I think your are using filter_by in a wrong way. You need to use the column name as parameter:

```
.filter_by(user_id=current_user.id)
```

Comment: Just added the error codes, hope that helps. Thanks for taking a look, I tried your suggestion, got back 
NameError: name 'user_id' is not defined

Comment: If with .filter_by(user_id==current_user.id) you get back no results check your post table. May be you have a problem inserting the data.

Comment: When I do: filter(Post.user_id==current_user.id), I get back no results. Looking at my table I see user_id is there under the Post table: https://ibb.co/Fn4bL8d so I suspect the error is with the current_user part?

Comment: You need to use only one `=` sign, not two. `filter_by` uses keyword arguments

Comment: filter(Post.user_id=current_user.id)                                                             
SyntaxError: expression cannot contain assignment, perhaps you meant "=="? Is the error I get when I use one =